# An Error Was Encountered Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found

Tags: error, ee

Besides database issues what causes this?????

I have not upgraded or moved the site.

I have set the permissions, checked my config.php file and so forth.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. We found the issue! We did check the database and exp sites and all was fine. I am using git to manage a website on a server and git had changed file permissions when we pushed from the development server to the live server. We needed to set permissions on a directory folder to get it to work. Problem averted! Slaves to our machines :(

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've ever seen it is when the settings in database.php were incorrect or there was a problem connecting to the database. Confirm with your host that your DB is still accessible.

Comment: +1 This has got to be a database-related issue. Most likely a connection issue as Nick said, but you can _also_ get this error if the database is empty or is missing a proper record in the `exp_sites` table.